# Assign to .GlobalEnv with assign

Tags: r, get, environment, assign

I have a function:

```
myfunctionIs=myfunct(x,y){
#Some calculations and assign my lists to globalenv
theList1<<-theList1
theList2<<-theList2

#Nested function
function(...){
theList1=get("theList1")
theList2=get("theList2")

##Some calculations...
#NamesList calculation
 NamesList= ###Some Calculations

ListContainer=c(deparse(substitute(theList1)),deparse(substitute(theList2)))

for (i in seq_along(ListContainer)){
        assign(ListContainer[i],mapply(function(x,y) {

          ##Some calculations

          return(x)      

        },x=get(ListContainer[i],envir=parent.env(environment())),y=NamesList,SIMPLIFY = FALSE),
        envir=.GlobalEnv)
      }

}}
```

I am trying to assign theList1 and theList2 back to .GlobalEnv but I get the error

```
Error in get(ListContainer[i], envir = parent.env(environment())) : 
  object 'structure(list("2002-12-31" = structure(list(Date = c("2000-01-31", ' not found
```

I believe that the error comes from

```
get(ListContainer[i],envir=parent.env(environment()))
```

Because the `calculations work correctly if I work in GlobalEnvironment`.

Any ideas? 
Best Regards

`EDIT`
That works:
Change `ListContainer` to:

```
ListContainer=c("theList1","theList2")
```

Was some issue with `deparse(substitute...` inside the function.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  This code is quite messy.  I can assure you the use of `<<-` and `assign` is almost certainly not necessary and I (almost) never use these.  Rather than assigning object to globalEnv, why don't you put all objects in a list and just work witht that?

Comment: @Andrie There are some reasons why the code is messy, but it is not the question here ;) And if you not use it, why should'nt I use it??

Comment: I don't use it, because there is probably a much easier way.  You ask for "any ideas".  I have lots of ideas, but it will help a lot if you describe what you really want to do.

Comment: @Andrie I am trying to assign the ListContainer (modified theList1 and theList2) to global environment. Which does not work when inside function but works when I work in GlobalEnv. An other solution would be to modify theList1 and theList2 and assign within child function.

Comment: I can't replicate your error.  Please turn this into a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @Andrie See my edit, I found the solution.... Thanks for your responses anyway:)

Comment: Please add your solution into the answers, not the question. Answering your own question is encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works: Change ListContainer to:

```
ListContainer=c("theList1","theList2")
```

Was some issue with `deparse(substitute(..))` part.

Or maybe that could work too with some adjustments:

```
ListContainer=c(quote(theList1),quote(theList2))
```

and then

```
eval(ListContainer[i])
```

in the loop.